# Do I need to use both PHP and Javascript for computation?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a page that uses javascript for computing inventories.

I use PHP as my server-side language for saving to MySQL.

What is the proper practice when it comes to this situation:

Use only php to compute then save to DB.

Use only javascript to compute then use PHP to save to DB.

Or should I use both to compute? Please help. Thanks

Comment: never trust the client. javascript is always clientside, so people can send whatever they want. If you want something to be reliable and have certain rules, write it in PHP.

Comment: You can write validation on both **client-side** and **server-side** because `client-side` is not reliable and you should not trust it As @meyer9 said, However it will make your app more dynamic especially if you use **ajax** requests

Comment: If it needs to be done in an environment that the Client is not supposed to see, you'll need to use the Server. For instance you would not want to make a JavaScript text encryption, then have decryption code on the Server to undo it, because the Client would have access to the code, which they could then use to hack your site. If you're just auto-creating passwords, that's okay on the Client Side, with SSL, because the Client knows their password anyways, and auto-creating passwords is not really a secret.

Comment: Personally, I would use PHP to handle MySQL data and `echo json_encode()` it back to your JavaScript, handling the DOM on the Client Side with JavaScript.

Comment: @PHPglue could you give an example please. Thank you.

Comment: Client Side code is visible to anyone that has access to your page on the internet. What's to know?

Comment: the encrypted text to DB

Comment: I keep tables of VARCHARs in a separate secure database with the Salts for use with another table that I keep TINYBLOBs and BLOBs in using AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT(), to store and extract results respectively. So, if you have SSL, it's okay to send the data without encrypting it on the Client Side, and just store the encrypted values as TINYBLOBs and BLOBs using AES_ENCRYPT().

Comment: wow... that's good. I could now see it clearly... tnx @PHPglue I need to code back :)

Comment: Yes, encrypt the database, just in case anyone breaks in (which you could argue, would only slow them down), SSL handles that between the Client and the Server.

Comment: tnx @AmrAly for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript for dynamic data calculations or adjustments client side without the need of refreshing the page. This is good if you are wanting to do on the fly calculations quickly in the clients browser

Use php for validating and formatting your data before saving into your MYSQL database. Make sure only send the raw inputs to your php script and do the calculations again with php server-side. Sending the computation result done with JS would be super risky as client side processing is easily manipulable by users.

Comment: Oh I see... so its best still to use the server-side language... Thank you for thought @Jason Joslin